# Is it possible to define functions and computed properties after ractive init?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I'd like to define/init ractive first, then load a script that sets up data, functions and computed properties.
Unfortunately while it works for data, ractive cannot find/parse functions added after it was initialized.

Is there a way to do it, or should I give up and initialize ractivejs at the very end of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add functions to the data object after initialisation...

```js
ractive.set('formatDate', locale.formatDate); // {{formatDate(today)}}
```

...but the same isn't true for computed properties. If there's a compelling use case for that, by all means [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues) – it's certainly something we could look into.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping for computed properties, but it's not like I can't change sequence of loading scripts.